# Python slow for-loop in async func

Tags: python, for-loop, python-asyncio, discord, pafy

I am trying to and `Song-Objects` to my `Queue-Object`, to get the actual songs I loop over a `Playlist-Object` from the libary `Pafy`.

```
playlist = pafy.get_playlist("playlist url here")
counter = 0
for s in playlist["items"]:
    counter += 1
    s = s["pafy"]
    song = Song.Song(s.watchv_url, msg.author.name, s.title, s.description, s.author, s.published, s.duration,
                     s.likes, s.dislikes,
                     s.viewcount, s.thumb)
    if queue.add_song(song=song):
        print("Song " + str(counter) + " finished")
    else:
        print("Song " + str(counter) + " not added")
```

---

```
class Song:
    def __init__(self, url, requested_by, title, description, uploader, upload_date, duration, likes, dislikes, views, thumbnail):
        self.url = url
        self.requested_by = requested_by
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.uploader = uploader
        self.upload_date = upload_date
        self.duration = duration
        self.likes = likes
        self.dislikes = dislikes
        self.views = views
        self.thumbnail = thumbnail
```

---

```
class PlayerQueue:
    list_of_songs = []
    length = 0
    current_song = []
    replaying = False
    random = False

    def add_song(self, song):
        try:
            self.length += 1
            self.list_of_songs.append(song)
            return True
        except Exception:
            return False

    def remove_song(self, song):
        if song in self.list_of_songs:
            self.length -= 1
            self.list_of_songs.remove(song)
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def replay(self):
        self.replaying = True

    def randomize(self):
        self.random = True

    def clear(self):
        self.list_of_songs = []
        self.length = 0
        self.replaying = False
        self.random = False
```

Should I make the `add_song-Method` async too?

it takes approximately 1-2 sec for looping over this code once.
This leads me into a problem with `asyncio`, because it will throw an `TimeoutError`. This error occurs after 30 seconds and for 70 Songs the loop takes more than one minute. Is this loop so slow, because it's run in a `async def function`? Can I even make it faster?

**Here is the error:**

```
    ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
    future: <Task finished coro=<VoiceClient.poll_voice_ws() done, defined 
    at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py:269> exception=TimeoutError()>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 239, in _step
        result = coro.send(None)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 276, in poll_voice_ws
        yield from self.ws.poll_event()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 676, in poll_event
        msg = yield from asyncio.wait_for(self.recv(), timeout=30.0, loop=self.loop)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 396, in wait_for
        raise futures.TimeoutError()
    concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError
```

Can I make a new task for my for-loop in a existing `asyncio.event.loop` so I don't run into this `TimeoutError`? Should I just try to catch it and then continue?

[Full code here](https://github.com/Stegosawr/Dino-Bot)

**Currently running on:**

Intel I5 Series CPU

64 GB DDR4 Ram

Python 3.x

Comment: How exactly do you create the asyncio task? Where do the `Song` class and the `add_song` queue method come from?

Comment: I am creating the task after getting a command input and the calling it normally in a `async def get_playlist_ready()`. [myBot](https://github.com/Stegosawr/Dino-Bot)

Comment: Could it be that `get_playlist` itself takes a long time to complete? How large is the `playlist["items"]` list?

Comment: In my test case I used a playlist that has 76 songs in it.When I debugged to me it looked like it doesn't take that long. So `playlist["items"]` has 76 objects in it.

Comment: *for 70 Songs the loop takes more than one minute* Have you tried to measure where this minute is spent? Looking at the loop, it's hard to imagine it taking a minute to execute.

Comment: while debugging the `song = Song.Song(attributes)` takes a long time, very long time

Comment: That is... surprising. How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: I mean it might be the `debugger`, but everytime I ran over the step of creating the `Song-object`, it took very long rill it continued. It might be that all the object in the `playlist-object` aren't loaded yet.

Comment: Ok, it's slow because Pafy objects retrieve their information lazily. You didn't indicate who is raising the timeout error, but judging from the traceback it is some sort of voice client for `discord`. Maybe you should ensure that the information you need is already available once this is activated? (The 30-seconds timeout for a "voice client" appears reasonable.) As written the question requires a design/debugging session, which is outside the scope of StackOverflow. Please edit it to clearly state the problem and include a **minimal** and **reproducible** example that demonstrates it.

Comment: I mean if it's lazily there is not much I can do about it.I would get the data myself with the gdata libary, but the installer of that has an error currently so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using another, library to download the playlist. I am using the `thread library` to run it sepretly so, before joining a vc I start the download in a separate thread, so I don't get a `timeout error`.